# 'views' is not defined in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My app is called courses and I can't import my urls.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', course.urls), 
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
]
```

And I always get this error

```
NameError: name 'courses' is not defined
```

Comment: how are you getting that error? what's the URL you're navigating to? more info.

Comment: you import views (last url), you don't import course (first url)

Comment: It said that the courses(from courses.url) in  url(r'^courses/', courses.urls), is not defined. I already tried include('courses.urls) and still doesnt worked.

Comment: You didn't `import courses.urls`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich 'Cannot import name urls' error

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#include) function when trying to include other urls

```
url(r'^courses/', include(course.urls)),
```

Note: `admin.site.urls` is a special case and doesn't require the use of include since it does magic

Comment: Whenever I import the include() from the conf I still get an error. 'cannot import url' whenever I import the include, vice-versa

Comment: @Jackskiee - That is a different issue for which you may need to ask a new question for. Although make sure to include what you've tried and researched to try to fix it